# is it possible Sniffing requests in android like Chrome developer network does?

Tags: android, security, google-chrome-devtools, sniffing

I have an android 7.1 rooted.

I would like to know if there is any app that does anything like "f12" on chrome (network tab)

I have identified some apps that sniff the packets but they have neither the interface nor what i want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can connect your device to a laptop acting as an access point running a proxy server, you can monitor the traffic. There are already solutions that do this for you. An example setup can be found [here](https://medium.com/@hackupstate/using-charles-proxy-to-debug-android-ssl-traffic-e61fc38760f7).

Comment: It's seems to much a hassle to configure laptop/pc for that, but i guess there shouldn't be any other way, thanks!

Comment: An answer has to contain all relevant information directly in the answer and not as link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to debug your application (you have access to the source code) then there is a great application [Stetho](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/#features) developed by Facebook which behaves exactly like you need - network inspection UI is served by  Chrome Developer Tools. Moreover it has a lot of other nice features: database inspection, view hierarchy inspections, etc.

Comment: Does it work if you don't have access? 
What if you are doing black box tests?

Comment: No it doesn't. The point is that you have to set the library as application dependency and manually set http interceptor to your okHttp client.